# Why does this code not return a string?

Tags: java

```
public String toString()
    {
        System.out.println(lastName + ", " + firstName);
        System.out.println(phoneNumber);
        if (relationship == 'F')
            System.out.println("Friend");
        else if (relationship == 'M')
            System.out.println("Family Member");
        else if (relationship == 'B')
            System.out.println("Buisness Associate");
        else System.out.println("Not Specified");
    }
```

This does not work because it says the code does not return a string, and I don't know why.

Comment: Where is _a_ `return` statement?

Comment: It does return a string. On the system output.

Comment: Why would you think it does return a string?

Answer (score 6):

Because you're not using `return <variable>` statement in your code. Printing in the `System.out` stream **IS NOT** the same as returning a `String`.

Instead printing the desired content of the String to output, it would be better to append all of it into a String and return this String to the client.

Here's an example:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(lastName)
        .append(", ")
        .append(firstName)
        .append('\n')
        .append(phoneNumber);
    if (relationship == 'F')
        result.append(" Friend");
    else if (relationship == 'M')
        result.append(" Family Member");
    else if (relationship == 'B')
        result.append(" Business Associate");
    else result.append(" Not Specified");
    return result.toString();
}
```

Also, try that the `toString` method returns a way to understand the data stored in your object. This is another example:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("Name: ")
        .append(lastName)
        .append(", ")
        .append(firstName)
        .append(". Phone Number: ")
        .append(phoneNumber)
        .append(". Relationship: ");
    if (relationship == 'F')
        result.append(" Friend");
    else if (relationship == 'M')
        result.append(" Family Member");
    else if (relationship == 'B')
        result.append(" Business Associate");
    else result.append(" Not Specified");
    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println` only prints to the console, it does not return an object.

Answer (score 1):

Try to return string like below:

```
public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(lastName + ", " + firstName);
    output.append(phoneNumber);
    if (relationship == 'F')
        return output.append("Friend").toString();
    else if (relationship == 'M')
        return output.append("Family Member").toString();
    else if (relationship == 'B')
        return  output.append("Buisness Associate").toString();
    else return  output.append("Not Specified").toString();
}
```

Comment: This was just for OP's understanding how he can return the value.

Comment: The example is still wrong. You should avoid using `System.out.println` in this method. Also, you're only returning a value for the `relationship` variable, which is `char` and doesn't have an `equals` method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no return statement. Instead of printing the properties you should be building a string to return (improving the formatting of the returned String is left as an exercise for the reader):

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    s.append(lastName).append(", ").append(firstName);
    s.append(phoneNumber);
    if (relationship == 'F')
        s.append("Friend");
    else if (relationship == 'M')
        s.append("Family Member");
    else if (relationship == 'B')
        s.append("Buisness Associate");
    else s.append("Not Specified");

    return s.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you would use a "toString()" function, it would be used like this

```
// replace "Person" with what your class is actually named
String personString = Person.toString(); 
System.out.println(personString);
```

So, instead of actually printing to the console in your application, you need to tell the `toString()` function, what value it needs to return.

You use the **return** keyword to do that

---

Try this

```
public String toString()
{
    String result = lastName + ", " + firstName;
    // feel free to change `result` more
    return result;
}
```

---

Take not of the method signature

```
public String toString()
```

that `String` in the signature is what's telling the compiler that the method is supposed to return a string.